# How to migrate collections from Mongodb to Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

We are currently running on MongoDB but are now interested in moving over to Cloud Firestore.  We have not found any tools for such a task so our planned approach is to create a "schema aware" script that makes a special sequence of queries from the MongoDB, and for each document create a new entry in Firestore while creating a map between the old mongo _id and the newly assigned id in Firestore.  These maps will be used in later queries in the sequence that need to make reference to other documents in other collections.

Has anyone else tried something similar or found a better, more general purpose tools for the task?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."